# Retain route for respective guard logins after logout via address bar

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I've got multiple guards. All are working fine.

However if a role log out (unauthenticated) from the app and I want to access any e.g `/admin/*` except `admin/login`  page via address bar, it doesn't redirecting and retain the `/admin/login` route. it's redirecting to `/login` instead. It applies to other roles too. How do I do to retain it?

Comment: You should not use multiple guards for this. You should use a single guard and authorise admin users using gates instead.

Comment: the business requirement imposes me to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the default built-in `\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate` middleware to handle authentication then that will throw an `AuthenticationException` along with the guards that were checked. You can handle the exception differently by overriding the `unauthenticated` in your exception handler:

**App/Exceptions/Handler.php**

```php
class Handler extends ExceptionHandler {
    //...Other code
    protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception) {
         if (in_array('admin', $exception->guards()) && !$request->expectsJson()) {
             return Redirect::guest('/admin/login');
         } 
         return parent::unauthenticated($request, $exception);
    }
```

corrected by OP